# How to implement a PriorityQueue without using the Java class?

Tags: java, class, queue, priority-queue

I'm trying to make a PriorityQueue without using the PriorityQueue class provided by Java. For this, I have some given methods that I have to fill in. I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake. It seems that my put and get functions are both wrong, and I'm not sure how to make a new PQ as is given in the code. What I have is the following:

```
class Element {

private int priority;
private String data;

Element(int priority, String data) { 
    // Ihr Code
    this.priority = priority;
    this.data = data;

 }

public String getData() { 
    // Ihr Code
    return data;
}


public int getPriority() { 
    // Ihr Code
    return priority;
 }

/**
 * Return data and priority as string 
 * Format: Data (Priority)
 * e.g: abc (7)
 */
public String toString()        {
    String str = data + " " + Integer.toString(priority) + ")";  
    return str;
}
}


public class PriorityQueue {


static final int SIZE = 32;


private Element[] data = null;

// actual number of entries
private int len = 0;


/**
 * Creates a new PriorityQueue
 */
public PriorityQueue() {
    // Ihr Code      
}

/** 
 * Adds a new element into the queue as long as there is space
 * Returns true if element could be added, otherwise false 
 */
boolean put(Element element) {
    // Ihr Code
    if(len == SIZE){
        return false;
    }else{
        int i = len-1;
        while (i>=0 && element.getPriority() > data[i].getPriority()){
            data[i+1] = data[i];
            i--;
        }
        data[i+1] = element;
        len++;
        return true;
    }

}

/**
 * Returns element with the highest priority 
 * and removes it from the queue. Otherwise returns null
 * 
 */
Element get() {
    // Ihr Code
    if (len > 0){
        Element x = q[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < len; i++){
            data[i-1] = data[i];
        }
        len--;
        return x;
        }else{
             return null;
        }
    }

/**
 * Number of entries 
 */
int length() {
    // Ihr Code
    return len;
 }

/**
 * Returns contents of the queue as a String
 * Format: data1 (priority1), data2 (priority2)
 * e.g: abc (7), cde (8)
 * Attention: There should be no comma at the end of the String 
 */
public String toString() {
    //  Code
    String res = new String();
    //res = "(" + data + "," + ")";

    if(data.length>0){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(String s: data){
            sb.append(s).append(",");
        }
        res = sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1).toString;
    }

    return res;
 }
```

I'm also struggling with the final toString method, to return the queue as a String in the format given, I tried something with a StringBuilder, but this doesn't compile correctly. Alternatively, I could make it with a normal for loop, but again I'm struggling with the exact syntax.

I found resources on the net to build this PQ with heap structures (which I have not had yet) and with a class called Comparator that I failed to understand. Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm mainly struggling with the

```
public PriorityQueue(){
      //what code?}
```

function. How am I supposed to make a "new" PQ here? Is it supposed to be

```
PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue();
```

I'm quite lost! Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Have you looked at the max-heap datastructure? This will be useful for this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PriorityQueue` constructor has to initialize the array and set the current number of items. That is:

```
public PriorityQueue() {
    data = /* initialize array */
    len = 0;
}
```

You really don't need to keep the elements in the queue in order. Just make your `put` method add the item as the next element in the array:

```
public put(Element e) {
    if (len == SIZE) {
        return false;
    }
    data[len++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

And then your `get` method searches the array for the highest-priority item, saves it, replaces that with the item at the end of the array, and returns:

```
Element get() {
    if (len == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        if (data[i].getPriority() < data[p].getPriority()]) {
            p = i;
        }
    }
    Element e = data[p];
    // replace with the last item
    data[p] = data[len-1];
    --len;
    return e;
}
```

So `put` is an O(1) operation and `get` is O(n). In your code, both are O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The constructor just needs to initialise the `Element[]`:

```java
public PriorityQueue() {
    data = new Element[SIZE];
}
```

Now to `put()`. This method will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` in the `while` loop since you start with `i = len - 1` which is the last field of `data`. Then you access `data[i+1]` which does not exist, and the exception will be thrown (unless, of course, you initialise it with `data = new Element[SIZE + 1]`).

Solution: just use `i` and `i-1` instead:

```java
boolean put(Element element) {
    if (len == SIZE) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // EDIT: I changed i = len - 1 to i = len since, otherwise,
        // the last element would always be overwritten. Now, the
        // last element gets copied to the first "free" element and
        // so on.
        i = len;
        while (i > 0 && element.getPriority() > data[i-1].getPriority()) {
            data[i] = data[i - 1];
            i--;
        }
        data[i] = element;
        len++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I said before that the element with the *smallest* priority would be returned. Actually, it is the *greatest*.

The `get()` method behaves as expected (except it should say `Element x = data[0]` instead of `q[0]` at the beginning). It returns the first element of the array (the one with the greatest `getPriority()` value) and moves the rest one index down. If, however, you want the element with the *smallest* value to be returned, just switch the `>` to `<` in the `while` loop of the `put()` method:

```java
while (i > 0 && element.getPriority() < data[i-1].getPriority()) {
    ...
}
```

Last but not least, the `toString()` method. It looks mostly right, except for the for-each loop. This one *always* iterates over the *whole array* where it should only iterate up to `data[len - 1]`. So, just use an index instead and you should be fine:

```java
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(data[i]).append(",");
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Alternatively, if you have at least Java 8 installed, you can use streams for this method:

```java
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.asList(data).stream()
        .limit(len)
        .map(Element::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the answer. Your explanation makes total sense and I noticed the toString() mistake myself. As for the rest of the code, I changed it to how you explained, but unfortunately it doesn't seem like it passes the tests that this assignment was given with. `org.junit.ComparisonFailure`for the `get` and `put` tests. 

The `toString()` method is correct, but only with me changing the `data[i] = element` to `data[i+1] = element` in the `put` method. 

There is some sort of issues with the indexes I think. Any further help would massively appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I had to change the `if` statement to get the tests to work, but now they do. Unfortunately, me changing the if statement has made the `toString` test not pass anymore as it did before I changed my statement. I cannot paste the code here as I'm going over the character limit, but I changed the `else` in the `put`method to an `else if (len > 0 && len < 32)` and it worked. Do you have any idea why the `toString` method doesn't work anymore? I cannot get the Strings to even print from my main method. 

Thanks so much for the help!

```

Comment: Uhh, it seems it was already late yesterday, lol. I made some mistakes in my code. I'm gonna update my answer and put in the correct code (which, this time, I tested). Also, I was mistaken when I said that get() returns the smalles priority value. It returns the greatest.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The `get` and `put` methods are correct according to my test cases, but unfortunately, the `toString` method is still failing. For some reason, I cannot get the data array to print on to the console, or to pass the tests. It worked with a previous version of the code, where put and get didn't work, but now that those 2 work, the `toString`doesn't. Extremely confused. Is there a possibilty you could look at the toString method again and help me out? I'm confused as to why nothing is being printed at all.

Comment: Hmm... I tested it using `javac` and `java` commands directly from PowerShell (with an additional `main` method) and it worked like a charm. What are you running it on? A console as well or inside an IDE (eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, ...)? Also, what exactly does the test look like? (I suppose it's a JUnit test?)

Comment: I've just looked at the `toString()` javadoc again. Could the mistake be that there is no whitespace after each `,`? In that case you would just need to `append(", ")` after each element and, in the end, replace `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1)` with `sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length())`.